# Calculate percentage change in rolling time window

Tags: python, pandas

The mock dataframe looks like this:

```
  server_name            log_time  occurrence_in_1h
0           A 2018-05-01 08:00:02                 1
1           B 2018-04-30 15:20:43                 1
2           B 2018-05-01 15:06:58                 1
3           C 2018-04-30 21:07:52                 1
4           C 2018-04-30 22:02:34                 1
5           C 2018-04-30 22:07:31                 2
6           D 2018-04-30 01:20:39                 1
7           D 2018-04-30 01:20:39                 2
8           D 2018-04-30 01:20:39                 3
```

And I wanna get the percentage difference of each server in `occurrence_in_1h` column, which looks like this:

```
  server_name            log_time  occurrence_in_1h  occurrence_in_1h_pct_change
0           A 2018-05-01 08:00:02                 1                          0.0
1           B 2018-04-30 15:20:43                 1                          0.0
2           B 2018-05-01 15:06:58                 1                          0.0
3           C 2018-04-30 21:07:52                 1                          0.0
4           C 2018-04-30 21:28:17                 2                          0.0
5           C 2018-04-30 22:02:34                 1                          0.0
6           C 2018-04-30 22:07:31                 2                          1.0
7           C 2018-04-30 22:15:08                 3                         0.5
8           D 2018-04-30 01:20:39                 1                          0.0
9           D 2018-04-30 01:20:39                 2                          0.0
10          D 2018-04-30 01:20:39                 3                          0.0
```

I've tried using

```py
df.set_index(['log_time']).groupby(['server_name'])['occurrence_in_1h'].rolling('1h').apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]) / x.iloc[0])
```

It would give `occurrence_in_1h_pct_change` in row 4 a `1.0`, and actually it's not calculating the `occurrence_in_1h_pct_change` **across** the `1h` time window, but **inside** the `1h` time window. The same situation happened on row 9 and row 10 which should be `0.0` too.

I know it's because that there is not a previous `1h` time window for those rows to calculate, but how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: What is `"serial_number"`? You don't have this column in your example dataframe

Comment: @AndrejKesely Sorry, I've edited it to `'server_name'`